# After build , api start returns html document instead of json?

Tags: node.js, express

I am going to deploy project but when I build it and connect frontend and backend api start returns html document instead of json. In app, you can log in and add friend from users of the app. Login, signup or update profile works good but When I go to friends page, there are no users to add to friend list and I get error 'is not valid JSON'

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-theme="light">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>SUP</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-IKfp9L5X.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-Tp3Y03jI.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

</body>
```

i go to postmen to test endpoint and I get the same result on all GET requests

Example: GET request `http://localhost:5000/api/user/`  to get all users
In result i get the same html doc.

the endpoint:

```
export const getUserList = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Get user list");
    try {
        const loggedInUserId = req.user._id;
        const filteredUsers = await User.find({ _id: { $ne: loggedInUserId } }).select("-password");

        res.status(200).json(filteredUsers);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in getUsersForSidebar: ", error.message);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
};
```

I can't find the cause of it. Before I `npm run built` everything was working without errors but now.
The build script is default.

```
"build": "npm install && npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

Comment: well, my bad the problem was in build process as i guess. i had app.get("*", (req, res) => {...} above all other routes and that make other route unreachable , so i just move it down

Answer (score 0):

well, my bad the problem was in build process as i guess.
i had app.get("*", (req, res) => {...} above all other routes

```
 here
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/message", messageRoutes);
```

and that make other route unreachable,
so i just move it down

```
    app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
    app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
    app.use("/api/message", messageRoutes);
 here
```

I thought it doesn't matter where u place it because other routes still execute by call, but no.